# Understanding the definition of general knowledge between agents

Tags: logic, artificial-intelligence

**Background**

Consider a set of possible states, $W$. An agent, $i$ has knowledge of a fact $E\subseteq W$, $K_iE=\{w|\sim_i[w]\subseteq E\}$, where $w\in W$ and $\sim_i[w]=\{w'|(w, w')\in\sim_i\}$ is the set of all states indistinguishable from $w$ for agent $i$. (In other words, $i$ has knowledge of $E$ in state $w$ if $i$ also has knowledge of $E$ in state $w'$ for all $w'$ indistinguishable from $w$.)

A group of agents have general knowledge that $E$ at $w$ if all agents know $E$ at $w$. Mathematically, $$KE=\bigcap_i K_iE.$$

**The problem**

Consider the following situation: there are 3 states, $\{w_1, w_2, w_3\}\in W$, and two agents, Ann and Bob. For Ann, $w_1$ and $w_2$ are indistinguishable, so $\sim_{\text{Ann}}=(w_1, w_2)$. For Bob, $\sim_{\text{Bob}}=(w_2, w_3)$.

What is the general knowledge in state $w_3$?

**My approach**

We need to determine $K_\text{A}E$ and $K_\text{B}E$ at state $w_3\in W$.

At $w_3$, there are no states indistinguishable from $w_3$ for Ann, apart from $w_3$ itself. So $K_AE=\{w_3\}$.

For Bob, $w_2$ and $w_3$ are indistinguishable, so in state $w_3$, $K_BE=\{w_2, w_3\}$.

Hence, we get $KE=\{w_3\}\cap\{w_2, w_3\}=\{w_3\}$.

But on my lecture slides it says that the correct answer is $\{w_2, w_3\}$.

**Questions**

Where is my lack in understanding of how to correctly apply these mathematical definitions?

What is a good solution to obtain the correct answer?

Any general pointers in using these definitions would be useful for others too.

**Edits/important points**

$\sim_i$ is an equivalence relation and $\sim_i\subseteq W\times W$.

$KE$ *is* general knowledge, $K_i E$ is the knowledge of any single agent.

Comment: I don't notice any flaws in your logic, but are your lecture slides publicly available?

Comment: It appears that the reasoning in your approach doesn't depend on what $E$ is at all -- that looks fishy. In fact, what _is_ $E$ in this exercise?

Comment: I think E=$\{w_3\}$

Comment: @VanillaThunder: In that case $K_{\rm B}$ would be $\varnothing$ because Bob is _never_ sure that he's in an $E$ state.

Comment: you're right, thanks!

Comment: @HenningMakholm I think $E$ is everything known in any of the worlds by both agents from position $w_3$. Does that make sense?

Comment: So thinking about it, perhaps an interpretation of general knowledge could also be: the set of states that are known by all agents independently. Would that make sense?

Comment: As some minor nits, you seem to intend $\sim_i$ to be an equivalence relation, but this isn't stated (except perhaps implicitly as you seem to be working in an epistemic modal logic) and has some impact on the answer. More objectively, ${\sim_{\text{Ann}}}=(w_1,w_2)$ is, at best, an abuse of notation. You could say "the smallest equivalence relation such that $w_1\sim_{\text{Ann}}w_2$" or, in this case, just write out ${\sim_{\text{Ann}}}=\{(w_1,w_2),(w_2,w_1)\}$.

Comment: As far as I can tell, the problem isn't that you did or did not apply the definitions correctly, but that you haven't presented a mathematical definition of "general knowledge in state $w_3$".

Comment: Reading closer, I think @Derek is right. Are you sure there isn't a definition somewhere that defines "general knowledge", possibly based on the definition of "group knowledge" you have presented.

Comment: Note that in your example $\{w_2,w_3\}$ happens to be the smallest $E$ such that $w_3\in KE$. This suggests a _possibility_ for what "general knowledge" might mean.

Comment: I've edited the question (see the bottom) to address some points. @DerekElkins

Comment: Your edited question now appears to claim in one place the $KE$ means group knowledge and in another place that $KE$ means general knowledge,

Comment: @HenningMakholm Apologies! Edited to remove all mentions of the word 'group' and replaced with 'general'